# Exclude elements from Google snippet?

Tags: seo, googlebot

I have an ecommerce store based on Magento. I have meta descriptions and keywords for all pages.

The problem is that in Google many of the snippets only show a little piece of the meta description and then it shows a couple of products from that page.

My site automatically sets the currency depending on the users location so when it shows the products in the snippets the currency is always USD as I guess google crawls it from the US and hence sees the prices in USD.

As most of my sales are to the UK I think it puts people off when they see the USD currency symbol in the SERP's.

Is there a way to prevent the currency symbol or the price from showing in the snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make sure that when the User Agent is googlebot you display the price in Pound.

Answer (score -1):

Have separate pages for each currency and use rel hreflang to indicate what country they relate to.